# How to transfer objects from different isolation modes in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two figures (constructed by many objects) in a .ai file (adobe illustrator cc). I'd worked on them separately, in that I'd just used live paint bucket tool for each one then expand the results, separately. Now, seemingly, each one has its own isolation mode. Assume an object just like a line in fig. A. I want to copy that object and use in fig. B. Reasonably, I should enter the isolation mode of fig. A, then copy the target line and place that at the desired location in fig. B. But the problem is that as soon as I exit the isolation mode of fig. A, the copied line is no longer visible in fig. B.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Select the objects with the Selection Tool (black arrow), and click the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button in the Control Bar across the top of the screen.

This will expand the Live Paint groups to normal groups. You can then copy/paste between them the same as you would any other group (but they won't be "live" live paint object any longer).

Comment: At the top the screen there is no such button, but `Object > Expand` button is inactive for them.

Comment: I even tried firstly `Expand Appearance` then `Expand`(as stated here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/grouping-expanding-objects.html) for both groups, buth copy/paste is still problematic

Comment: I should have ungrouped the source group before copying its element. As I did, it would worked. Thanks... But why does the copying process depend on group or ungroup properties?! Even when the objects of source group were grouped, I was selecting the target object and copying that!